# Hopf Bifurcation Analysis

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have to study the presence of an Hopf Bifurcation in a dynamical system with 4 equations. I have found a criterion of Hopf bifurcation without using eigenvalues, in which the bifurcation is called SIMPLE Hopf bifurcation because a condition is that all the eigenvalues must appear with non negative real part. Is there any criterion for obtaining Hopf bifurcations without using eigenvalues? So I could locate the presence of the traditional Hopf bifurcation, not only the SIMPLE one. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain your question? What do you mean by "I have found a criterion of Hopf bifurcation **without using eigenvalues**", if you said that the criterion is that all **eigenvalues** have non negative real part?

Comment: The criterion I am talking about can be found in the free .pdf  
"Criterion of Hopf Bifurcations without Using Eigenvalues" by  Liu

Answer (score 0):

Detailed information on this criterion can be found in the book: [Time and Space in Economics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-4-431-45978-1_9). For a computational implementation, you can refer to the work I published not long ago in the Wolfram Function Repository: [BialternateSum](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BialternateSum/).